# Camunda-worker-node gets me Error: Cannot find module ‘xtend’

Tags: node.js, camunda

I’m a beginner at camunda and I want to use it to control what is going on in nodejs.

I cloned https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples.git, installed the JS code…

did the npm install, but when I run, I get: “Cannot find module ‘xtend’” but I can see that it is in the nodemodules directory.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Error: Cannot find module 'xtend'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/Tristan/Documents/Codes/Javascript/repos/camunda-worker-node/lib/workers.js:1:76)
at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. It's the fault of `camunda` devs that have forgotten to add `xtend` to their package.json. Perfect opportunity for you to make a pull request and add it!

As a workaround you can do `npm i xtend -S`